# pcl 3D Object Recognition and Tracking using Kinect

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any one can advice me, I have a kinect and I want to use it to do the object recognition and make sure the position, PCL is available.3D Object Recognition and Tracking using Kinect .Can any one help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211236/pcl--3d-object-recognition-and-tracking-using-kinect/) by [Roslj](https://answers.ros.org/users/22780/roslj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-06-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) on 2015-07-06**:
Hi @Roslj! Have you tried [this](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/correspondence_grouping.php#correspondence-grouping)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try once ORK(object recognition kitchen).

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2016-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0